# Function not running on setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I’m trying to update values in a table pulled in from MySQL but the function is not re-running?

Alternatively, if there is another solution to allow me to update the values from the MySQL database on a 60 second interval please let me know.

EDIT: error has been resolved but now i get a new error instead of replacing the mysql value in the table cell it adds new cells into the table what part of the code would need to be changed or added to resolve this?

The code below returns no errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log(1+0);
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        var len = response.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var beacon = response[i].beacon;
            var location = response[i].location;


            var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'> <span class='minutes'>00</span>:<span class='seconds'>00</span> </td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
        }
    setInterval(updateTable, 10000);
}
    })
})

        function updateTable() {
                    console.log(1+1);
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        var len = response.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var beacon = response[i].beacon;
            var location = response[i].location;


            var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
            }

}
});
};

</script>
```

Comment: Why is `setInterval(updateTable, 10000)` _inside_ `updateTable`?

Comment: Regarding the edit: if your original question has been answered, then please mark that answer as the answer and then ask a new question.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have marked the answer as correct and didnt want to ask to many questions as i have previously been marked down by users for asking to many question and blocked for 90 days from asking any more questions

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware people were down-voting for asking follow up questions.  That seems to be the rule here - ask a question, get an answer, don't change the question.  Maybe add your follow-up as a comment to the answer, sometimes people are nice and follow up if it's not too much extra work.

Comment: As for your edit: this code adds new cells: `$("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);`

Comment: thank you do you have a recommendation as to what i could either look for or change it to so that it updates rather than adds new cells? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you format it well you'll see that youre `setInterval` is inside your function...
You sould place it in the `$(document).ready` callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
      var len = response.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var beacon = response[i].beacon;
        var location = response[i].location;


        var tr_str = "<tr>" +
            "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
            "<td align='center'> <span class='minutes'>00</span>:<span         class='seconds'>00</span> </td>" +
            "</tr>";

        $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
      }
      // <===== You should place youre set interval here
    }
  })
});

function updateTable() {
  console.log(1 + 1);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
      var len = response.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var beacon = response[i].beacon;
        var location = response[i].location;


        var tr_str = "<tr>" +
            "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";

        $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
      }

    }
  });
  var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `setInterval(updateTable)` from *inside* `updateTable`.

You're not calling `updateTable` from anywhere *outside* of `updateTable`, which means the function is never running, and the `setInterval` is never executed.

To fix, either:

1. Put your `setInterval` *outside* of `updateTable`, or
2. Add `updateTable()` to the end of your script.

I recommend the former.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setInterval,

`setInterval(updateTable, 10000);`

try using setTimeout after you process and update the table:

```
function updateTable() {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    ,complete: function(data){
       // do something
       setTimeout(updateTable, 10000);
    ...
  });
}
```

This will allow your code to wait for the information to arrive prior to make another request and not be considered a DoS attack.

Let me know if this works for you or not. We can try something else.